# How to get reproducible results in keras

Tags: python, numpy, theano, keras

I get different results (test accuracy) every time I run the `imdb_lstm.py` example from Keras framework (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py)
The code contains `np.random.seed(1337)` in the top, before any keras imports. It should prevent it from generating different numbers for every run. What am I missing?

UPDATE: How to repro:

1. Install Keras (http://keras.io/)
2. Execute https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_lstm.py  a few times. It will train the model and output test accuracy.
   Expected result: Test accuracy is the same on every run.
   Actual result: Test accuracy is different on every run.

UPDATE2: I'm running it on Windows 8.1 with MinGW/msys, module versions:
theano 0.7.0
numpy 1.8.1
scipy 0.14.0c1

UPDATE3: I narrowed the problem down a bit. If I run the example with GPU (set theano flag device=gpu0) then I get different test accuracy every time, but if I run it on CPU then everything works as expected. My graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 635)

Comment: I cannot replicate running the code on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `theano -> 0.6.0`, `numpy -> '1.9.2'`, `scipy ->  '0.15.1'
`

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I use Windows.  
numpy.random.uniform works fine, always produces same results.

Comment: I narrowed the problem down a bit. If I run the example with GPU (set theano flag device=gpu0) then I get different test accuracy every time, but if I run it on CPU then everything works as expected. My graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 635)

Comment: Code for GPU must use `SIMD`-like instructions a lot. This may result in random generator being called in random order. Also GPU is rather an autonomous entity and it may use its own random generator. After all, it's not trivial to run any code you want on GPU.

Comment: check out:
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/rng_mrg.html and 
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html .
In order to get the same results every time on the GPU you'll have to add to some of the keras functions to be able to seed them properly on the GPU

Comment: Which CUDA version did you use?  Did you install cuDNN?  The latter I believe makes some sacrifices for speed that results in non-deterministic behavior on gpu.  (Should be slight, I think it has to do with atomic operations being calculated on the backrprop, but you wouldn't get the same value every time.)

Comment: CUDA 7.5, and I used cuDNN

Comment: If you run your code on multiple CPUs, can you also face the issue of RNG being called in random order?

Answer (score 80):

You can find the answer at the Keras docs: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development.

In short, to be absolutely sure that you will get reproducible results with your python script **on one computer's/laptop's CPU** then you will have to do the following:

1. Set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
2. Set the `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
3. Set the `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
4. Set the `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
5. Configure a new global `tensorflow` session

Following the `Keras` link at the top, the source code I am using is the following:

```
# Seed value
# Apparently you may use different seed values at each stage
seed_value= 0

# 1. Set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)

# 2. Set the `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import random
random.seed(seed_value)

# 3. Set the `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed_value)

# 4. Set the `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
# for later versions: 
# tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(seed_value)

# 5. Configure a new global `tensorflow` session
from keras import backend as K
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
# for later versions:
# session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
# sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
# tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

It is needless to say that you do not have to to specify any `seed` or `random_state` at the `numpy`, `scikit-learn` or `tensorflow`/`keras` functions that you are using in your python script exactly because with the source code above we set globally their pseudo-random generators at a fixed value.

Comment: For later versions of tensorflow, if you face an error, use *tf.random.set_random_seed(seed_value)*

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! Just to be sure: Is there anything I need to do to "restore the randomness back to normal" after running the script? Or does setting the seed_values only have a "one-time effect"?

Comment: Hey @Frank, I think that it does not go back to normal if you set the seed values like that unless you restart the kernel etc (or set a different seed value by yourself etc).

Comment: @Outcast On the link to Keras docs you sent `First, you need to set the PYTHONHASHSEED environment variable to 0 before the program starts (not within the program itself)`. Isn't your answer settings the `PYTHONHASHSEED` "within the program itself" (`os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)`) ?

Answer (score 16):

In Tensorflow 2.0 you can set random seed like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(221)


from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers


model = keras.Sequential( [ 
layers.Dense(2,name = 'one'),
layers.Dense(3,activation = 'sigmoid', name = 'two'),
layers.Dense(2,name = 'three')])

x = tf.random.uniform((12,12))
model(x)
```

Answer (score 13):

Theano's [documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/sandbox/randomnumbers.html) talks about the difficulties of seeding random variables and why they seed each graph instance with its own random number generator.

> Sharing a random number generator between different {{{RandomOp}}}
>   instances makes it difficult to producing the same stream regardless
>   of other ops in graph, and to keep {{{RandomOps}}} isolated.
>   Therefore, each {{{RandomOp}}} instance in a graph will have its very
>   own random number generator. That random number generator is an input
>   to the function. In typical usage, we will use the new features of
>   function inputs ({{{value}}}, {{{update}}}) to pass and update the rng
>   for each {{{RandomOp}}}. By passing RNGs as inputs, it is possible to
>   use the normal methods of accessing function inputs to access each
>   {{{RandomOp}}}’s rng. In this approach it there is no pre-existing
>   mechanism to work with the combined random number state of an entire
>   graph. So the proposal is to provide the missing functionality (the
>   last three requirements) via auxiliary functions: {{{seed, getstate,
>   setstate}}}.

They also provide [examples](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/examples.html) on how to seed all the random number generators.

> You can also seed all of the random variables allocated by a
>   RandomStreams object by that object’s seed method. This seed will be
>   used to seed a temporary random number generator, that will in turn
>   generate seeds for each of the random variables.

```
>>> srng.seed(902340)  # seeds rv_u and rv_n with different seeds each
```

Comment: But in order to seed them, we need to have access to theano's random objects that keras will use. Is it possible to do via keras API?

Answer (score 12):

I finally got reproducible results with my code. It's a combination of answers I saw around the web. The first thing is doing what @alex says:

1. Set `numpy.random.seed`;
2. Use `PYTHONHASHSEED=0` for Python 3.

Then you have to solve the issue noted by @user2805751 regarding cuDNN by calling your Keras code with the following additional `THEANO_FLAGS`:

3. `dnn.conv.algo_bwd_filter=deterministic,dnn.conv.algo_bwd_data=deterministic`

And finally, you have to patch your Theano installation as per [this comment](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1935#issuecomment-194359606), which basically consists in:

4. replacing all calls to `*_dev20` operator by its regular version in `theano/sandbox/cuda/opt.py`.

This should get you the same results for the same seed.

Note that there might be a slowdown. I saw a running time increase of about 10%.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is now solved in Tensorflow 2.0 ! I had the same issue with TF 1.x (see  [If Keras results are not reproducible, what's the best practice for comparing models and choosing hyper parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59075244/if-keras-results-are-not-reproducible-whats-the-best-practice-for-comparing-mo) ) but

```
import os
####*IMPORANT*: Have to do this line *before* importing tensorflow
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(1)

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow.keras.layers 
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def reset_random_seeds():
   os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(1)
   tf.random.set_seed(1)
   np.random.seed(1)
   random.seed(1)

#make some random data
reset_random_seeds()
NUM_ROWS = 1000
NUM_FEATURES = 10
random_data = np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS, NUM_FEATURES))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=random_data, columns=['x_' + str(ii) for ii in range(NUM_FEATURES)])
y = df.sum(axis=1) + np.random.normal(size=(NUM_ROWS))

def run(x, y):
    reset_random_seeds()

    model = keras.Sequential([
            keras.layers.Dense(40, input_dim=df.shape[1], activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
            keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
        ])
    NUM_EPOCHS = 500
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=NUM_EPOCHS, verbose=0)
    predictions = model.predict(x).flatten()
    loss = model.evaluate(x,  y) #This prints out the loss by side-effect

#With Tensorflow 2.0 this is now reproducible! 
run(df, y)
run(df, y)
run(df, y)
```

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
SEED = 123456
import os
import random as rn
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import set_random_seed

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
set_random_seed(SEED)
rn.seed(SEED)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is easier that it seems. Putting only this, it works:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random as python_random

def reset_seeds():
   np.random.seed(123) 
   python_random.seed(123)
   tf.random.set_seed(1234)

reset_seeds()
```

The KEY of the question, VERY IMPORTANT, is to call the function reset_seeds() every time before running the model. Doing that you will obtain reproducible results as I check in the Google Collab.

Comment: This approach almost worked for me. I had to add `os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = str(seed_value)` to the beginning of the function body and then it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I have trained and tested `Sequential()` kind of neural networks using Keras. I performed non linear regression on noisy speech data. I used the following code to generate random seed :

```
import numpy as np
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
```

I get the exact same results of `val_loss` each time I train and test on the same data.

Comment: Have you used GPU? What backend: Theano or TensorFlow?

Comment: I used CPU with Theano backend.

Comment: Got it. CPU works fine for me too. I have issues only when running on GPU.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add something to the previous answers. If you use **python 3** and you want to get reproducible results for every run, you have to

1. set numpy.random.seed in the beginning of your code
2. give PYTHONHASHSEED=0 as a parameter to the python interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous comment, but reproducible results sometimes needs the same environment(e.g. installed packages, machine characteristics and so on). So that, I recommend to copy your environment to other place in case to have reproducible results. Try to use one of the next technologies:

1. [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). If you have a Linux this very easy to move your environment to other place. Also you can try to use [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/).
2. [Binder](http://mybinder.org/). This is a cloud platform for reproducing scientific experiments.
3. [Everware](http://everware.xyz/). This is yet another cloud platform for "reusable science". See the [project repository](https://github.com/everware) on Github.

Comment: My problem is that I can't get reproducible results even on the same environment when I run the training twice.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what has been said before, **only Tensorflow seed has an effect** on random generation of weights (latest version Tensorflow 2.6.0 and Keras 2.6.0)

Here is a small test you can run to check the influence of each seed (with np being numpy, tf being tensorflow and random the Python random library):

```
# Testing how seeds influence results
# -----------------------------------

print("Seed specification")

my_seed = 36
# To vary python hash, numpy random, python random and tensorflow random seeds
a, b, c, d = 0, 0, 0, 0

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(my_seed+a) # Has no effect
np.random.seed(my_seed+b) # Has no effect
random.seed(my_seed+c) # Has no effect
tf.random.set_seed(my_seed+d) # Has an effect

print("Making ML model")

keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('float64')

model = keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(2, input_shape=input_shape),#, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(output_nb, activation=None),
    ])
#
weights_save = model.get_weights()

print("Some weights:", weights_save[0].flatten())
```

We notice that variables `a`, `b`, `c` have no effect on the results.
Only `d` has an effect on the results.

So, in the latest versions of Tensorflow, **only tensorflow random seed has an influence** on the random choice of weights.