# Which seeds have to be set where to realize 100% reproducibility of training results in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-seed

In a general tensorflow setup like

```
model = construct_model()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    train_model(sess)
```

Where `construct_model()` contains the model definition including random initialization of weights (`tf.truncated_normal`) and `train_model(sess)` executes the training of the model -

Which seeds do I have to set where to ensure 100% reproducibility between repeated runs of the code snippet above? [The documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed) for `tf.random.set_random_seed` may be concise, but left me a bit confused. I tried:

```
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
model = construct_model()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        train_model(sess)
```

But got different results each time.

Comment: You also need to remove parallelism from your computation because that is often non-deterministic, turn off GPU and use `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=1,intra_op_parallelism_threads=1)`

Comment: Also, some non-determinism is caused by using modern instruction sets like SSE (see [here](http://blog.nag.com/2011/02/wandering-precision.html) ), so to get 100% reproducibility you may need to recompile TF without using SSE

Comment: Just for clarification, the above `sess = tf.Session...` in the comments does not turn off the GPU, as observed by `watch nvidia-smi` (in the case of an nvidia gpu, as on AWS EC2 p2.xlarge instances)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419510/how-to-get-reproducible-results-in-keras?noredirect=1&lq=1 might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution which works as of today with GPU is to install tensorflow-determinism with the following:

```
pip install tensorflow-determinism
```

Then include the following code to your code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
```

source: https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow-determinism

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is that when constructing the model, there are some code using numpy.random module. So maybe you can try to set the seed for numpy, too.

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me is following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52897216/5049813) with a few modifications:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random

# Setting seed value
# from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52897216
# generated randomly by running `random.randint(0, 100)` once
SEED = 75
# 1. Set the `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(SEED)
# 2. Set the `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
random.seed(SEED)
# 3. Set the `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
np.random.seed(SEED)
# 4. Set the `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
```

I was not able to figure out how to set the [session seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142951/tensorflow-2-0-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-session) (step 5), but it didn't seem like it was necessary.

I am running Google Colab Pro on a high-RAM TPU, and my training results (the graph of the loss function) have been exactly the same three times in a row with this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
SEED = 42
import os
import random

os.environ["TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS"] = "1"
keras.utils.set_random_seed(SEED)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
```