# Making neural network training reproducible using RStudio's Keras interface

Tags: r, rstudio, keras, keras-layer

I'm trying to make neural network training reproducible using RStudio's Keras interface. Setting a seed in the R script (`set.seed(42)`) doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to pass seeding as an argument to `layer_dense()`? I can choose `RandomUniform` as an initializer but I'm having difficulty passing a seeding argument along with it. The following line throws an error:

`model %>% layer_dense(units = 12, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(8), kernel_initializer = "RandomUniform(seed=1)")`

But a layer can be added without the attempt to pass a seed argument:

`model %>% layer_dense(units = 12, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(8), kernel_initializer = "RandomUniform")`

`RandomUniform` is suppose to take a seed argument according to the [Keras initializer documents](https://keras.io/initializers/).

Comment: I am using keras in python and it seems to work when I do `set.seed(42)` and `import tensorflow`, `tensorflow.set_seed(42)`. Can you explicitly import tensorflow in R and try that? Also, it only works when working with CPUs, not with GPUs.

Comment: I think I should try to use the R Tensorflow library instead of the R Keras library because Keras is integrated in Tensorflow 1.2

Answer (score 4):

```
library(keras)
use_session_with_seed(42)
```

The use_session_with_seed() function establishes a common random seed for R, Python, Numpy, and Tensorflow. For further details, see https://keras.rstudio.com/articles/faq.html

Answer (score 3):

kernel initializer argument syntax should be like this. `kernel_initializer=initializer_random_uniform(minval = -0.05, maxval = 0.05, seed = 104)`

Try these steps.

1) Set seed for R environment before importing keras/tensorflow

2) Set tensorflow session configuration to use single thread

3) Set tensorflow random seed

4) Create tensorflow session with this seed and assign it to keras backend.

5) Finally in your model layers, if you are using random initializers like random_uniform(this is the default one) or random_normal then you will have to change the seed argument to some integer
Below is an example

```
# Set R random seed
set.seed(104)
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

# TensorFlow session configuration that uses only a single thread. Multiple threads are a 
# potential source of non-reproducible results, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022950/which-seeds-have-to-be-set-where-to-realize-100-reproducibility-of-training-res
#session_conf <- tf$ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads = 1L, 
#                               inter_op_parallelism_threads = 1L)

# Set TF random seed (see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed)
tf$set_random_seed(104)

# Create the session using the custom configuration
sess <- tf$Session(graph = tf$get_default_graph(), config = session_conf)

# Instruct Keras to use this session
K <- backend()
K$set_session(sess)


#Then in your model architecture, set seed to all random initializers.

model %>% 
    layer_dense(units = n_neurons, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(100),kernel_initializer=initializer_random_uniform(minval = -0.05, maxval = 0.05, seed = 104)) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = n_neurons, activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer=initializer_random_uniform(minval = -0.05, maxval = 0.05, seed = 104)) %>%
    layer_dense(units =c(100) ,kernel_initializer=initializer_random_uniform(minval = -0.05, maxval = 0.05, seed = 104))
```

References: 
https://rstudio.github.io/keras/articles/faq.html#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development
https://rstudio.github.io/keras/reference/initializer_random_normal.html#arguments

Answer (score 3):

As of TensorFlow 2.0:

```
library(tensorflow)
tensorflow::set_random_seed(42)
```

See also [this discussion](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/1330#issuecomment-1106720859).