# How do I get reproducible results with Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have seen [this FAQ](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) and this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230448/how-to-get-reproducible-result-when-running-keras-with-tensorflow-backend) about reproducibility in keras and TF 1.x. How do I do something similar in TF 2.0 because it no longer has `tf.Session`? I know I could still set the graph seed and the seed for each initialization in the layer by passing something like `tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(seed=10)`. However, I am wondering if there is something more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `tf.random.set_seed(seed)` at the startup. In my use cases it provides reproducible results.