# "TypeError: 'Session' object is not callable" error running sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, random-seed, reproducible-research

I'm trying to set seeds and configure keras settings to ensure my experiments are reproducible. When I run the following (based on code in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230448/how-to-get-reproducible-result-when-running-keras-with-tensorflow-backend)):

```
# Import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2

# for setting seeds and configuring keras so that experiments are reproducible
from numpy.random import seed
import random as rn
import os
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

seed_num = 1

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '0'
np.random.seed(seed_num)
rn.seed(seed_num)

session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)

tf.random.set_seed(seed_num)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
```

...an error occurs:

> TypeError: 'Session' object is not callable

What do I need to change to get this to run successfully and ensure that my experiments are reproducible?

I'm running tensorflow version 2.1.0 in a Jupyter Notebook on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line second to last, you probably want to construct a `Session` object using the arguments `graph` and `config`, not *call* a `Session`.

Change this:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
```

to this:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
```

You will also need to change the code in the fourteenth line:

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras import backend as K
```

Since Tensorflow 2.0, Keras does not expose sessions in the backend like before. You can get around that by using the `compat.v1` API, but this is soon to be deprecated.

Comment: The change suggested results in a different error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_session'

Comment: I have edited my answer to solve the issue. The way the Tensorflow 2.0 API is structured makes it easy to do a lot of things without actually working directly with `Session`s, so there may be a more TF-2.0 way of doing this. There is a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127576/how-do-i-get-reproducible-results-with-tensorflow-2-0).