# Cannot get Reproducible Results with Keras CNN Model

Tags: python, numpy, keras, random, tensorflow2.0

I have read several other posts about how to get reproducible results using tensorflow/keras. However, I am still getting varying results.

The additional random components of my script include a sklearn.train_test_split() which I set a random_state = 123456 and also a `ImageDataGenerator` from Keras for data augmentation. I am setting the seed there as well.

Below is the code and where I set the seed. I am running my model for 1 epoch to compare the accuracies and they are different every time. I am setting the random seeds at the top of my code and then within the functions I use the random state. If I don't utilize the `random_state` in `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` or `seed` in `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` I also do not get the same results.

```
# seeding necessary for neural network reproducibility at top of the code
SEED = 123456
import os
import random as rn
import numpy as np

os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
rn.seed(SEED)

# within another function
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = validation_size, random_state = 123456)

# in the model building function
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range = 15,
    width_shift_range = 0.1,
    height_shift_range = 0.1,
    horizontal_flip = True
    #zoom_range = [0.5, 1.0] # half zoom to double zoom possibilities
)
data_generator.fit(xtrain, seed = 123456)
```

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error. I found there is a library for NVIDIA GPU (which I am using) that will give me deterministic results.

First I install the library with `pip install tensorflow-determinism`
Then set os environment variable:

`os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'`.
I am now getting reproducible results:

```
Test error: 1.6772334575653076, test accuracy: 0.5085999965667725
```

```
Test error: 1.6772334575653076, test accuracy: 0.5085999965667725
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem are how the keras model parameters are initialized. You can specify your own initializers to get reproducible behaviour as documented [here](https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/)

Comment: Why wouldn't my global seeding handle that? Surely keras is using tensorflow's seed and I cover that, right?

Comment: @Coldchain9 look at the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230448/how-to-get-reproducible-result-when-running-keras-with-tensorflow-backend they covered it already

Comment: A lot of these discussions are saying I need to disable my GPU to get reproducible results. That just isn't feasible for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Think I found a solution. I need to ```pip install tensorflow-determinism``` and ```os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'``` at the top of my code. Looks like I am getting same results across training sessions now. Thank you for leading me in the right path.