# Keras Fixing Seed effect on traning data shuffling

Tags: keras, shuffle, training-data, seed

I'm new in keras and i have one question.

To get reproducible result, i fixed seed. If the fit function shuffle parameter is true, is traning data order  always same for all epochs or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you set the seed correctly to a certain value the training order should always be the same with the same seed. However I there were some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836857/results-not-reproducible-with-keras-and-tensorflow-in-python) regarding reproducibility when using TF and multiprocessing. I'm not sure if this is solved by now.

You can also checkout [this site in the Keras Documentation.](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development)

Comment: Thanks for answer. because of the non-determinstic algorithm of cuDNN, results can be slightly different, but effect of this is very small.

Comment: These results in the Stackoverflow link were produced using CPU, but GPU probably does not better.