# Keras Default Backend in Python & R

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I am very confused after reading a lot about keras and tensorFlow, and still have some basic questions in my mind.

My confusion started from the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59462354/discrepancy-between-rs-keras-and-pythons-keras-accuracy-bug), where he writes keras **standalone** and `from tensorflow.keras import keras`.

1- (Python case):

Does keras use any backend when I write this line of code `import keras`, and No single line of code related to tensorflow e.g `tf.keras` or `tf.keras.layers` in my full implementation of the model, but only  `import keras`? if it does, then is there any way to check what backend is being used?

2- Same question in the case of R Language.

3 - Is TensorFlow only used as backend when we write `import tensorflow as tf` and `import tf.keras` ?

4- Does `import keras` and `import tf.keras` have any discrepency in performance and accuracy in case of python?

5- Does versions of keras and tensorFlow have an impact in performance and accuracy in both language (R and Python) ?

6- What could be the reasons to have 5% accuracy difference in R and Python. Python gives 94%, while the same implementation in R gives 89% accuracy. The versions of keras & tensorFlow in R are 2.3.0, 2.2.0, while the versions in Python are : tf: 2.3.0, keras: 2.4.3. Please [see this one](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/956).

Comment: FYI the [multi-backend version of keras has been discontinued](https://github.com/keras-team/keras#multi-backend-keras-and-tfkeras), and in the future, users should use `tf.keras`.

Comment: @jakub thank you so much for your comment. In future, if i use import keras only, will it work or not? if it works then will tensorflow automatically be used?