# What are the sources of non-determinism in Tensorflow parallel computing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, non-deterministic

To achieve deterministic results in Keras / Tensorflow, it is (among other things) necessary to "deactivate parallelism", as stated in the [Keras doc](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development):

```
# Force TensorFlow to use single thread.
# Multiple threads are a potential source of
# non-reproducible results.
# For further details, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022950/which-seeds-have-to-be-set-where-to-realize-100-reproducibility-of-training-res

session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022950/which-seeds-have-to-be-set-where-to-realize-100-reproducibility-of-training-res) also states that (in the comments):

```
You also need to remove parallelism from your computation because that is often non-deterministic
```

What makes Tensorflow parallel computations non-deterministic?

Comment: This question is given the fact that common parallel computations (BLAS operations for example) are deterministic.

Comment: Actually this happens on CPU tasks (`intra_op_parallelism_threads=1` does not exist for GPUs)