# Tune the hyperparameters of Keras: different results for the same parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, grid-search, hyperparameters

I try to tune the hyperparameters

```
def create_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=10, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# create model
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1)
# grid search epochs, batch size and optimizer
epochs = [ 100, 150, 170, 200, 250]
batches = [ 5, 10, 20, 25, 30]
param_grid = dict(epochs=epochs, batch_size=batches)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv = cv)
```

then fit

```
%%time
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And I get

```
grid_result.best_params_, grid_result.best_score_
({'batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 150}, 0.31568432165371191)
```

After that I make **all the same** and get

```
grid_result.best_params_, grid_result.best_score_
({'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 100}, 0.31368631761629029)
```

What is the problem? Dataset's size

```
X_train.shape, y_train.shape
((1001, 10), (1001, 4))
```

I think we must get Identical results using `random_state` but `KerasClassifier()` has not `random_state`

Comment: Its probably just the effect of random initialization of the weights of the network.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419510/how-to-get-reproducible-results-in-keras