# Reproducible results with keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How can I get reproducible results with keras? I followed [these](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) steps but I am still getting different results every time I run the Jupyter notebook. I also tried setting `shuffle=False` when calling `model.fit()`.

My configuration:
conda 4.3.25

keras 2.0.6 with tensorflow backend

tensorflow-gpu 1.2.1

python 3.5

windows 10

Comment: Are you training on GPU or CPU?

Comment: You may be facing this issue: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2280

Comment: @McLawrence I am using gpu

Comment: @DanielMöller I already checked that reference and tried setting the number of threads to 1.

Comment: I  don't know how strong your results vary, but even if you set the random seed for all used libraries, the implementation of convolutions in cuDNN is non-deterministic by default. So if you are using CNNs, that could be the reason. You can disable it, as described [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2479#issuecomment-213987747).

Comment: @McLawrence maybe you could add your comment as an answer as it seems to be factually correct and answers the question OP had.

Comment: the answer linked is using Theano...the question is for Tensorflow...

Comment: Please have a look at my response here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52897216/9024698) for when using the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer I posted at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121117/9501391). The main idea is to: first, disable the GPU. And then, seed the libraries like "numpy, random, etc". To sum up, including the code below at the beginning of your code may help solve your problem.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random as rn
from keras import backend as K

sd = 1
np.random.seed(sd)
rn.seed(sd)
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(sd)

config = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
tf.set_random_seed(sd)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=config)
K.set_session(sess)
```