# Keras getting different results with set seed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In keras, each run has a high variance and unstable performance. To combat this according to https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development. I set the seeds as shown.

Unfortunately this does not help and I continue to get mixed results. Any guidance would help.

```
# Seed value (can actually be different for each attribution step)
seed_value= 0

# 1. Set `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)

# 2. Set `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import random
random.seed(seed_value)

# 3. Set `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed_value)

# 4. Set `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(seed_value)

# 5. Configure a new global `tensorflow` session
from keras import backend as K
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
from itertools import permutations
import keras
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, concatenate, Lambda, Multiply, Add, Dropout, multiply, TimeDistributed, Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D, LeakyReLU
from keras.activations import softmax, sigmoid
from keras.models import Model
from keras_sequential_ascii import keras2ascii
from keras import backend as K
```

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping

```
# Custom loss to take full batch (of size beam) and apply a mask to calculate the true loss within the beam
beam_size = 10

K.clear_session()
def create_mask(y, yhat):
    idxs = list(permutations(range(beam_size), r=2))
    perms_y = tf.gather(y, idxs)
    perms_yhat = tf.gather(yhat, idxs)
    mask  = tf.where(tf.not_equal(perms_y[:,0], perms_y[:,1]))
    mask = tf.reduce_sum(mask, 1)
    uneq = tf.squeeze(tf.gather(perms_y, mask))
    yhat_uneq = tf.squeeze(tf.gather(perms_yhat, mask))
    return uneq, yhat_uneq

def mask_acc(y, yhat):
    uneq, yhat_uneq = create_mask(y, yhat)
    uneq = tf.argmax(uneq,1)
    yhat_uneq = tf.argmax(yhat_uneq, 1)
    #uneq = tf.Print(uneq, [uneq], summarize=-1)
    #yhat_uneq = tf.Print(yhat_uneq, [yhat_uneq], 'pred', summarize=-1)
    # argmax and compare
    #a = tf.Print(tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(uneq, yhat_uneq), tf.float32)), [tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(uneq, yhat_uneq), tf.float32))])
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(uneq, yhat_uneq), tf.float32))#tf.cond(tf.greater(tf.size(yhat_uneq), 1), lambda: tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(uneq, yhat_uneq), tf.float32)), lambda: 100.)

def beam_acc(y, yhat):
    #a = tf.Print(yhat, [yhat], 'pred', summarize=-1)
    #yhat = tf.Print(yhat, [yhat],'\nSTART', summarize=-1)
    yhat_uneq = tf.argmax(yhat, 0)
    # argmax and compare
    # do possible indexes and predicted index
    y = tf.reshape(y, [-1])
    #y = tf.Print(y, [y], summarize=-1)
    possible = tf.where(tf.equal(y, tf.constant(1.0,dtype=tf.float32)))
    yhat_uneq = tf.Print(yhat_uneq, [yhat_uneq], 'prediction')
    possible = tf.reshape(possible, [-1])
    #possible = tf.Print(possible, [possible], 'actual')
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(possible, yhat_uneq)), tf.float32))
    #mean = tf.Print(mean, [mean], 'mean\n')
    return mean#tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(possible, yhat_uneq)), tf.float32))#tf.cond(tf.equal(tf.reduce_sum(y), tf.constant(0.0)), true_fn=lambda: 0., false_fn=lambda: tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(yhat_uneq, possible), tf.float32)))

def mask_loss(y, yhat):
    # Cosider weighted loss
    uneq, yhat_uneq = create_mask(y, yhat)
    #yhat_uneq = tf.Print(yhat_uneq, [yhat_uneq], summarize=-1)
    #create all permutations and zero out matches with mask
    total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=tf.cast(uneq, tf.int32), logits=yhat_uneq))
    #d = tf.Print(yhat_uneq, [yhat_uneq], summarize=-1)
    #total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=uneq, logits=yhat_uneq))
    #total_loss = tf.Print(total_loss, [total_loss])
    return total_loss


x = Input((19,78))
lstm1 = LSTM(64, batch_input_shape=(10, 19, 78),return_sequences=True, unroll=True, activation='relu')(x)
#mult = multiply([encoded, ff])
#cat = concatenate([encoded, squeezed])
#dense2 = Dense(10)(encoded)
dense = Dense(1)(lstm1)
#mult = multiply([dense, prob])
#dense2 = Dense(1)(mult)
#print(dense2.shape)
output = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1))(dense)
#output = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x, -1))(added)
#lam2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1))(lam)
#probs_aug = Lambda(lambda x: x * .01)(probs)
#output = Add()([lam, probs])
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, nesterov=True, momentum=.9, decay=1e-5)
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001,decay=1e-5)#, nesterov=True, momentum=.9, decay=1e-5)
lstm_model = Model(inputs=[x], outputs=output)
lstm_model.compile(sgd, loss=mask_loss, metrics=[mask_acc, beam_acc])
filepath="weights.best.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_beam_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_beam_acc', patience=3) 
#lstm_model.fit([X_train], y_train, batch_size=10,epochs=10, verbose=1, shuffle=False,validation_data=([X_dev], y_dev))#, callbacks=[checkpoint, ])
           #, callbacks=[PlotLossesCallback()])

lstm_model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10,
               epochs=10, verbose=1, shuffle=False,validation_data=(X_dev, y_dev), callbacks=[checkpoint, stop])
               #, callbacks=[PlotLossesCallback()])
```

Comment: Do you run on GPUs?

Comment: I suggest you still use `np.random.seed(0)` or `tf.set_random_seed(0)` et the very start of your program and let me know if works.

Comment: This does not run on GPUs, and all seeds have been set at the beginning of the program as described in the link from keras.

Comment: Can you set momentum to 0?

Comment: Yeah I will try that once I get into work, will be back with an update in ~1hr

Comment: OK, meantime I will post some answer to this question to clarify the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was solved by setting the pythonhashseed at an os level using ([Reproducible results using Keras with TensorFlow backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631576/reproducible-results-using-keras-with-tensorflow-backend)):

```
# Seed value (can actually be different for each attribution step)
seed_value= 0

# 1. Set `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable at a fixed value
import os
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)

# 2. Set `python` built-in pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import random
random.seed(seed_value)

# 3. Set `numpy` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(seed_value)

# 4. Set `tensorflow` pseudo-random generator at a fixed value
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(seed_value)

# 5. Configure a new global `tensorflow` session
from keras import backend as K
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
K.set_session(sess)
```

Comment: Very good finding, in the particular [document](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) you used stands that this should be set from the environment, but is also possible  from within the code `os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=0`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you had both these lines:

```
np.random.seed(0) 
tf.set_random_seed(0)
```

Document you [mentioned](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) also states you can run it like this:
`PYTHONHASHSEED=0 python3 yourcode.py` to set the python hash seed.

Possible this would be the best way do eliminate the hash seed randomness.

This variable need to be set before launching the python process. 
`os.putenv()`, or in `os.environ` may not work in some Python version.

Comment: I updated my post, unfortunately this was not the issue, seeds are set and I am using SGD with no momentum.