# Reproducibility in Google Colab | Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras in Google Colab. I am doing transfer learning: trying different models/weights available in keras.applications. I am not developing a new model, just importing layers (except last one) and weights, and adding one final layer.

I need to get reproducible results: every time I run the same code I get the same results. I have tried different options (links below), but I cannot get reproducible results.

Please, any suggestions or code for this?

[How to get reproducible results in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419510/how-to-get-reproducible-results-in-keras)

https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development

[Tensorflow-Keras reproducibility problem on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305909/tensorflow-keras-reproducibility-problem-on-google-colab)

[Tensorflow-Keras reproducibility problem on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57305909/tensorflow-keras-reproducibility-problem-on-google-colab)

Thanks