# Executing CTNK algorithm in Weka. Reproducibility issues

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I want to execute a python script in Weka that is using Keras + CTNK as backend and so, build a neural network.

The script works finem but every time that I want to execute it, I have a different output. How could I keep the reproducibility in each execution?

Thanks

Comment: verify the documentation for random seed. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32687043/2237916) might also help.

Comment: @silgon thanks, I will check it out !