# What is the difference between activation layer and activation kwarg?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

What is the difference between activation layer and activation kwarg?

for instance :

`activation` kwarg :

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation="relu"))
```

`Activation` layer :

```
model=Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Activation("relu")
])
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/):

> Activations can either be used through an Activation layer, or through the activation argument supported by all forward layers

This quote is then followed by a specific example, which states that the following are equivalent:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation=activations.relu)) # or 'relu'
```

and

```
model.add(layers.Dense(64))
model.add(layers.Activation(activations.relu))
```

as you would expect.

Comment: but I'm getting different outputs and accuracy rate

Comment: @0xN1nja [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32419510/11659881) might be relevant.